# Avoid links navigating to same page

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using jsoup to do recursive crawl a web page.I have links like this

```
<a href ="#">hash</>
<a href ="#top">hashtop</>
<a href ="http://www.google.com">google</>
```

I don't have a problem with links like the third one. When u see first and second which will have the navigation within in the same page.When I do document. get to anchor tags I am getting same parent URL for # and parenturl#top for the second one.I don't want those kinds of links to fetch. Can some let me know how to avoid fetching those kinds of links in jsoup

Comment: show how you  fetch the other links

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following :

```
doc.select("a[href~=^[^#]")
```

This uses the [`[attr~=regex]` selector syntax](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) with a regex that will only match strings that do not start with `#`.